# Django segmentation fault while running in docker

Tags: django, docker

We are getting segmentation fault while running the application in docker

```
/path/condapy/envs/env_name/bin/python -vvvvvv manage.py runserver


# code object from 
'/path/condapy/envs/env_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/__pycache__/wsgi.cpython-36.pyc'
import 'django.core.wsgi' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f1919dd5a90>
import 'django.core.servers.basehttp' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f1919dca240>
import 'django.core.management.commands.runserver' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f1919dbf630>
import 'django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f1919db34a8>
PyThreadState_Clear: warning: thread still has a frame
Running in local mode
Performing system checks...

Segmentation fault
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:latest

ENV JAVA_VERSON=1.8.0 \
    JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java \
    codepath=<>

RUN yum install -y epel-release cmake wget git python-setuptools zlib-devel openssl-devel python-devel gcc-c++ snappy-devel gcc curl bzip2 java-$JAVA_VERSON-openjdk java-$JAVA_VERSON-openjdk-devel && \
    yum install -y nginx && \
    easy_install supervisor && \
    yum clean all && \
    rm -rf /etc/localtime && \
    ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata /etc/localtime && \
    mkdir -p  /logs 

RUN mkdir -p /path/condapy && \
    curl -sSL https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -o /srv/miniconda.sh && \
    bash /srv/miniconda.sh -bfp /path/condapy && \
    /path/condapy/bin/conda install -y python=3 && \
    /path/condapy/bin/conda update conda && \
    /path/condapy/bin/conda clean --all --yes

EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR /app_path

ARG aws_access_key_id
ARG aws_secret_access_key
ARG env

COPY ./conda_environment.yml /app_path/conda_environment.yml

RUN /path/condapy/bin/conda config --add channels conda-forge && \
    /path/condapy/bin/conda env create -f=/app_path/conda_environment.yml -n chatty && \
    rm -rf /opt/conda/pkgs/*

COPY ./ $codepath

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-n"]
```

DB config looks good and we have already assigned sufficient memory. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post dockerfile?

Comment: Don't base your image on Alpine Linux.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid its based on centos:latest

Comment: Update the question with your dockerfile, as mentioned by @deosha.

Comment: @deosha done. Its a trimmed down version of the dockerfile but it should be good enough.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid done

Answer (score 1):

You install python while building docker image. Try build you image from centos image with preinstalled python or build your image from multiple base images (docker since 17.05 supports that https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#before-multi-stage-builds)

Your Dockerfile will became seem like that:

```
# Include Base image with preinstalled python 
######
FROM centos/python-35-centos7
pip install ...
######

ENV JAVA_VERSON=1.8.0 \
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java \
codepath=<>
......
```

Comment: This looks interesting. Let me do it and get back to you.

Comment: I would develop separate docker images for django application and your core JAVA application. You can connect them together by REST API (for example) and deploy by docker-compose

Comment: The issue was because of the libraries using different version of gcc compiler. Thanks for your help.